# Using d3.json without reading from file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive graph using d3.js library. I want to alternate between feeding data into my d3 object from either a stored json file or directly from a dictionary (that gets created upon some user input).

To read from a file I use

```
d3.json('/path/to/file.json')
```

Upon user input a dictionary `d` is created. I tried using

```
user_file = json.dumps(d)
d3.json(user_file)
```

to no avail.

I have a workaround -- upon user input, create a `user_file.json` file with `json.dump(d, '/path/to/user_file.json')` and read directly from there with `d3.json('/path/to/user_file.json')`. Other than just feeling less elegant this adds the additional problem that the new json file gets cached.

Any advice? I'm new to javascript so advice on 'best practices' would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json()` normally has two arguments: the url ('/path/to/file.json') and the function that will handle the result which you leave out of your examples. This handler is often an anonymous function declared inside the call to `d3.json()`, but it can be a named function. I would define a named function to handle the json result, then just use the same function to handle the data created on user input.

```
function resultHandler(error, data){
    ... do stuff w/ data ...
}

d3.json('/path/to/file.json', resultHandler);

function userInputHandler() {
   ... create data ...
   resultHandler(null, d);
}
```